# powershell loop through arrary in arrary

Tags: powershell

I'm try to write a powershell script to create a folder and then create files inside that folder.

```
$arr = @(
            ("First Folder",@("1", "2")),
            ("Sceond Folderr", @("1","2"))
        )

for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr.length; $i++)
{
    #New-Item -Path $arr[$i] -ItemType directory
    for ($a=0; $a -lt $arr[$i].length; $a++)
    {
        $file=$arr[$a]
        #New-Item -Path "$file.txt" -ItemType File
        $file
    }
}
```

This is the result I get.

```
First Folder
1
2
First Folder
1
2
Second Folder
1
2
Second Folder
1
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$arr` variable is defined as a [jagged array](https://pwrshell.net/back-to-basics-arrays/):

> ***Jagged* arrays vs. *Multidimensional* arrays:**
>
> Both are useful for holding lists of lists or arrays of arrays.
>
> - Jagged is faster and use less memory than multidimensional, because it contains only the number of elements it needs.
> - A non jagged array is more like a matrix where every array must be the same size.

The following code snippet shows proper way of handling the particular jagged array `$arr`:

```
$arr = @(
            ("First Folder",@("1", "2")),
            ("Sceond Folderr", @("11","12"))
        )

for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr.length; $i++)
{
    $dire = $arr[$i][0]
    #New-Item -Path $dire -ItemType directory
    for ($a=0; $a -lt $arr[$i].length; $a++)
    {
        $file=$arr[$i][1][$a]
        #New-Item -Path "$dire`\$file`.txt" -ItemType File
        "$dire`\$file`.txt"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SU\1285156.ps1
First Folder\1.txt
First Folder\2.txt
Sceond Folderr\11.txt
Sceond Folderr\12.txt

PS D:\PShell>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I could understand why the folder was still showing in my second loop

Answer (score 1):

While StackOverflow would be a better place to post this, if you're working with PowerShell there is no real need to use classic for loops.

```
$arr = @(
            ("First Folder",@("1", "2")),
            ("Second Folder", @("1","2"))
        )

$arr | %{
    $folder = $_

    Write-Output $folder[0]

    $folder[1] | %{
        Write-Output "SubItem:", $_
    }
}
```

The `%` is a shortcut `ForEach-Object`. As for your solution use more descriptive variables names to make it easier to understand (for yourself).

```
$arr = @(
            ("First Folder",@("1", "2")),
            ("Sceond Folderr", @("1","2"))
        )

# ForEach item from 0 to 1
for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr.length; $i++)
{
    # ForEach item from 0 to $arr[$i].length
    # 0, 0 - 1, 0, 0 -1 
    for ($folderKey=0; $folderKey -lt $arr[$i].length; $folderKey++)
    {
        Write-Output "Value for `$i is $i and value for `$folderKey is $folderKey"

        # Always prints just what's on the index of $i
        $file=$arr[$i]
        $file

        # The fix would be $arr[$i][$folderKey]
    }
}
```

Comment: above array was just a example. i will have array 1 with 100 folder and then array 2 will have 100 files name.

Comment: i try this # The fix would be $arr[$i][$folderKey] but it was still showing the folders name, in 2nd loop i dont like to get the folders name because i dont want to create a file with folder name. is this normal

Comment: If you modify line 16 your output will be what you expect. Obviously you'd have to modify the code to suite your need. It's just there to point out the error you got in your original code. The above code currently only outputs the folder name.